# Quick question about a picture - area under a normal distribution is always 1

Tags: probability, statistics

Check out the picture below.

It's from this site: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html

All 3 curves (red, blue, green) are normal distributions **[Edit and solution to my question (thanks Hyperplane): Turns out they are not the curves of a normal distribution. I learned "Gaussian" does not necessarily mean a probability density function]**. Green is the convolution of blue and red.

**My question**

I know the area under all normal curves is one (axiom of probability). But it seems like the red curve has the biggest area.

I know the convolution of two normals has a variance equal to the sum of the variance of $f$ and $g$... I feel this is a bad picture, but I know I'm wrong to accuse wolfram of that. Can you fix my intuiton? Is it really just all in the tails?

Sorry if this is the dumbest question ever.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you assume they are all probability densities?

To me it seems like they simply chose $g(x) = \tfrac{1}{2}f(2x)$. Hence green and blue should have the same area, but not blue and red.

I manged to recreate it in [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wba3sdaqr1). It appears that they used $f(x) = e^{-(2x)^2}$ and $g(x) =\frac{1}{2}e^{-(4x)^2}$, which gives $[f*g](x) = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{5}}e^{-\tfrac{16}{5}x^2}$. (Or values that are at least very close to this)

[image]

Comment: On the website it is says they are Gaussian curves... I believe that means they are legit probability density functions with areas of 1. Or perhaps they have the normal shape but are scaled as to not have an area of 1?

Comment: @HJ_beginner Gaussian curves is anything of the form $a e^{-b(x-c)^2}$, with $b>0$.

Comment: Ahh I believe you are correct then and that resolves the area not being 1. How about the variance... wouldn't the green curve be fatter than the red curve because its variance is equal to the variance of the blue and red curves added together? For example at the points $1$ and $-1$ it seems like it should be higher than the red curve. It seems like green and red have the same standard deviation. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: @Hyperplane You're right. According to the site, the red and green line are Gaussians (density functions of normal distributions), but they don't define the blue line as that. However, I am curious where you get your Gaussian curve definition from, because according to the site it is a density function of a normal distribution.

Comment: @ThePhenotype Almost everyone calls these curves gaussian. It's only when you do probability theory when you specifically imply that the total area needs to be $1$.

Comment: Thank you your answer has helped me immensely. I was wrong to assume they were talking about densities and I also was wrong (or ignorant) that Gaussian doesn't always mean normal pdf. I am learning about convolution for the first time through probability, so my mindstate was 100% probability when I was looking at the picture.

Comment: @HJ_beginner Glad I could help. When you do learn about convolution I would advise you to read up a bit on the Fourier Transform too, as it has an intricate relationship with convolution: $\mathcal F(f*g) = \mathcal F(f) \cdot \mathcal F(g)$

Comment: @Hyperplane Appreciate the tip, I will definitely do that. Convolution has been a difficult concept for me... so I'm checking out as many different resources as I can (which is how I landed on that wolfram page and got tripped up).

Answer (score 4):

You are right. The picture (and text) is misleading. To check that, look at the boxcar function. The area of $f$ and $g$ is definitely different

Comment: Ahh, this comment was helpful. My critical mistake was thinking that the Gaussians were probability density functions. But in the example they state before, the boxcar functions are not both uniform RVs because the area under the blue box looks to be less than $1$. That clued me that this page is not focused on probabilities and then I also learned today that Gaussian does not necessarily mean a probability density curve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The picture is not correct as Hyperplane has shown us.
So the areas are not equal.

Note that such a "huge-area-under-a-small-function-nuance" illusion does exist for other functions. We can compare the convergent integral
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_1^t\frac{1}{x^2}dx=\lim_{t\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{t})=1$$
and the divergent integral
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_1^t\frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{t\to\infty}\ln(t)=\infty$$

Both functions $\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ are very close to $0$ for $x>4$, but still the second integral keeps adding an unbounded amount of area as $t$ gets larger.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Those two functions are a very interesting example...  so basically the illusion is the tails are thicker for the green and blue curve than the red curve? For example, would it be safe to say that if $g$ is the blue curve then $g(1000) > f(1000)$? Sorry I am a super newb.

Comment: You're correct about the illusion. You could say that $g(x)>f(x)$ for large $x$ if the variance of $g$ is larger than that of $f$ if you look at their probability density functions (the $\exp(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})$ part). For this you should know the variance of each function, or you could use the "68"-part of the "68–95–99.7 rule" to visually determine their variances.

Comment: @The_Phenotype Apparently $g$ is not a Gaussian, so assume $g$ is another function that is a Gaussian.

Comment: There is definitely not a lot of area when the line is close to $0$, as it is exponentially decreasing. Your integrals are misleading as they picture polynomially decreasing functions.

Comment: @Hyperplane No, you're wrong. Both the green and red functions are Gaussians and the red one "seems" to have more area in the middle, so the integrals are equal and therefore the green one must have more area at the sides after both functions intersect. My integrals are not misleading: they are just examples to illustrate the illusion, doesn't matter what category of functions: we are just looking at the area in the picture.

Comment: @ThePhenotype did you read my answer? I pretty much reversed engineered the parameters they used. Not any one of these curves is a probability distribution. They all have area different then 1.

Comment: Did you even check out the link? "The animations above graphically illustrate the convolution of two boxcar functions (left) and two Gaussians (right)" Click on "Gaussian" and you get the corresponding definition.

Comment: @ThePhenotype I think Hyperplane is right, if you look at the boxcar example the blue rectangle clearly has an area less than 1. I wanted to learn about convolution as it applies to probability but this is just a general page about convolution. My bad.

Comment: @HJ_beginner They even explicitely state $f$ and $g$ under the picture as density functions for normal distributions! *Did any of you even read the page?*

Comment: @ThePhenotype So basically Hyperplane says that a Gaussian need not be the density of a normal RV. However wolfram does say it is right here  (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianFunction.html). But if you look at Gaussian in wikipedia it agrees with Hyperplane. I think the term "Gaussian" can be somewhat ambiguous then but the most broad definition I think agrees with Hyperplane. That's my thinking about all this... thanks for your help.

Comment: @HJ_beginner 1: Why would a site define something and NOT use the definition??? 2: They even explicitely state the boxcar functions and the density functions under the picture! Did you read the page?

Comment: @ThePhenotype yeah brother but look at the blue boxcar function. The area under that blue box is way less than $1$. So the blue boxcar is not a uniform random variable or a probability density function. So they already showed that they're not 100% doing probability density functions only. I hear you though it seems like they could have written this all better... but a novice like me criticizing wolfram is like me questioning God about this crappy planet he has created.

Comment: @HJ_beginner BLUE IS NOT A PROBABILITY DENSITY FUNCTION! I am only talking about the green and red one. Read carefully please!

Comment: @ThePhenotype Well then their definition of the word gaussian does not agree with how they use it. Assume the blue curve $g$ was a normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma)$. It has the unique maximum in $(0,\tfrac{1}{2})$, hence $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2=\tfrac{2}{\pi}$. Then $g(1) \approx 0.23$. However the blue curve  drawn is well below $0.1$ at $x=1$.

Comment: @Hyperplane NO ONE ASSUMED $g$ IS NORMAL! We are talking about the red and green ones. Please read everything carefully again.

Comment: @ThePhenotype If $f$ is normal, but $g$ is not, then $f*g$ can't be normal either.

Comment: @ThePhenotype Since $\int f*g dx  = (\int f dx) \cdot (\int g dx)$

Comment: Very, very fair point. I see I am in the wrong now.

Comment: @ThePhenotype I still stand by my point though that even if they were all Normal distribution, there cannot be much area hiding in the tail. You should be familiar with the [68-95-99 rule?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)  As soon are you are a few standard deviations away from the the maximum, there is almost no area left under the graph.

Comment: For a gaussian function the enclosed area is a constant multiple of (approximately, twice) the area of the rectangle delimited by the inflection points and the $x$-axis, so there is no "*large tails illusion*" and this is definitely not an answer.